# Tensorflow asking for placeholder feed_dict when not needed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run a piece of tensorflow code that shouldn't need a placeholder.

In the `run` method, `self.sess.run([solver...])` clearly needs a placeholder however the last line: `example = self.sess.run(self.p_Z(self.get_sample())` does not need a placeholder.

However if I do not add the feed_dict for `example` it gives me the error:

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,128]   [[node Placeholder
>   (defined at
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748)
>   ]]

```
class VAE:

    def __init__(self):

        self.data = all_data            
        self.X_dim = 128
        self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.X_dim])
        self.z_size = 2
        self.prior = tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(
                        loc=np.zeros(self.z_size, dtype='float32'),
                        scale_diag=np.ones(self.z_size, dtype='float32'))
        self.lr = 1e-4
        self.batch_size = 8

        self.sess = tf.Session()

    def get_next_batch(self, batchsize = 8):
        shuffle(self.data)
        return self.data[:batchsize]

    def q_Z(self):        
        h1 = tf.layers.dense(self.X, 100, tf.nn.relu)
        h2 = tf.layers.dense(h1, 100, tf.nn.relu)

        self.stdv = tf.layers.dense(h2, self.z_size, tf.nn.softplus)
        self.mu  = tf.layers.dense(h2, self.z_size)

        self.posterior = tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=self.mu,scale_diag=self.stdv)


    def get_sample(self):
        return self.posterior.sample()

    def p_Z(self, inp):

        with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            l1 = tf.layers.dense(inp, 100, tf.nn.relu, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE, name='l1')
            l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1, 100, tf.nn.relu, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE, name='l2')
            self.l3 = tf.layers.dense(l2, self.X_dim, tf.nn.relu, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE, name='l3')

        return self.l3

    def NLL(self):

        self.recon_cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=self.X, predictions=self.l3))
        self.kl_term = tf.reduce_mean(tfd.kl_divergence(self.posterior,self.prior))
        self.NLL_loss = self.recon_cost + self.kl_term #probably change name to ELBO


    def run(self):

        self.q_Z()
        self.p_Z(self.get_sample())
        self.NLL()

        solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.lr).minimize(self.NLL_loss)


        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(5000):
            _, loss, _klT, _rec = self.sess.run([solver,
                                                 self.NLL_loss,
                                                 self.kl_term,
                                                 self.recon_cost], feed_dict = {self.X: self.get_next_batch() })

            if epoch % 50 == 0:

                # ERROR HERE:
                examples = self.sess.run(self.p_Z(self.get_sample()))
```

Replacing the last line with: `examples = self.sess.run(self.p_Z(self.get_sample()), feed_dict = {self.X: self.get_next_batch(16)})`

removes the error, however the `feed_dict` shouldn't be needed. How do I fix this?

Comment: You use `X` in `q_Z` to make `h1`, `h2`, and `posterior`. You use `postieror` in `p_Z`. Everything's easier in tensorflow2: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae

Comment: @mdaoust Yes so I don't require `X` for `p_Z` so it shouldn't be asking me for a `feed_dict` in the last line.

Comment: @mdaoust how do I specify that I want the stored weights of h1 and h2 to get the posterior. The stored weights of h1 and h2 don't require X?

Comment: The problem here is that you think you're storing a value, but you're actually still building a graph. In fact on each iteration you'll be adding that new part to the graph over again. Either assign the value to a variable, or make everything a single `session.run` call.